# Parse the XML to get the Node Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml-parsing, xml-to-json

I get a XML response which is 16 MB data when calling an end point like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://example.org/edmx">
<edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema xmlns="http://example.org/edm" Namespace="PlatformForScience" Alias="pfs">
     <EntityType Name="VHP_BI_SAMPLE" BaseType="pfs.SAMPLE">
         <Property Name="JAX_SAMPLE_COMMENTS" Type="Edm.String"></Property>
         <NavigationProperty Name="SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST" Type="pfs.CMQ_REQUEST"
                             Partner="REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_VHP_BI_SAMPLE">
    </EntityType>
```

I need to parse my XML and look for the `<EntityType Name="VHP_BI_SAMPLE" BaseType="pfs.SAMPLE">` and get the `Partner` associated with the NavigationProperty Name="SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST" . I am not sure how to parse the XML with Angular JS or convert them in to JSON so I can access the Property, how can I do this

I am not sure how I can install the X2JS package from github in to my AngularJS project

Comment: Your xml appears invalid. Try to fix it first.

Comment: Yeah I just posted a portion of it as I cannot post the entire XML content

Comment: Can you use xpath?

Comment: I have not done it before. Can you please show me an example

Comment: See attempt at an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat modifying your xml to make it valid:

```
<EntityType Name="VHP_BI_SAMPLE" BaseType="pfs.SAMPLE">
         <Property Name="JAX_SAMPLE_COMMENTS" Type="Edm.String">
         </Property>
         <NavigationProperty Name="SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST" Type="pfs.CMQ_REQUEST"
                             Partner="REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_VHP_BI_SAMPLE">
        </NavigationProperty>
</EntityType>
```

The following xpath expression

```
EntityType[@Name="VHP_BI_SAMPLE"][@BaseType="pfs.SAMPLE"]/descendant::NavigationProperty[@Name="SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST"]/@Partner
```

will select

> REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_VHP_BI_SAMPLE

I believe this is what you're looking for.